# sql query for creating map of array in aws athena (presto)

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto, aws-glue

I have a table in aws athena with the following columns

```
Company name  Employee Name   Salary
------------------------------------
 Apple       | John         | 50
 Apple       | Dima         | 100
 Microsoft   | Bart         | 75
 Google      | Harry        | 90
 Google      | Noah         | 80
```

and I want to generate by a single query the following table preferably using map of arrays

```
Company name  Employee Data
------------------------------------
 Apple       | [John,50],[Dima,100]
 Microsoft   | [Bart,75]
 Google      | [Harry,90],[Noah,80]
```

Any idea on how it can be done?

Comment: is there a `listagg` function or something similar?

Comment: i have already solved it using arrayagg, but i afraid the the order of the values may not be the same, for example:




select 
company_name,
array_join(array_agg(salary),','),
array_join(array_agg(employee_name),',') 
from db.stats group by company_name;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no formal group concat function in PrestoDB.  But we can come close:

```
SELECT
    CompanyName,
    array_join(array_agg('[' || EmployeeName || ',' || Salary || ']'), ',', '') AS EmployeeData
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    CompanyName;
```